# is there a parameter, that makes ccxt fetch ohlvc from binance testnet?

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

i wrote a method to fetch ohlvc data from binance or bybit using ccxt.
I want to get the data from the testnet of these two exchanges.
How can i do that ?
I searched ccxt code a bit and found, that testnet urls are present for
the binance exchange, so that should be possible. Yet i can not figure out
how to set the thing.

I guess there should be some option like
binance_futures = ccxt.binance({ 'option': { 'defaultMarket': 'future' } })

Does anyone know ?

Comment: sorry for double post. this question has been answered already.

Comment: its: set_sandbox_mode(true)